# upload image,string,integer through Retrofit in one API

Tags: android

@FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("******")
        Call updateProfile(@Field("user_id") Integer user_id,
                                         @Field("profile_image") File profile_im,
                                         @Field("name") String name,
                                         @Field("mobile") String mobile,
                                         @Field("class_id") Integer class_id,
                                         @Field("address") String address,
                                         @Field("country_id") Integer country_id,
                                         @Field("state_id") Integer state_id,
                                         @Field("city_id") Integer city_id,
                                         @Field("session_id") String session_id

Answer (score 0):

@FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("******")
        Call updateProfile(@Field("user_id") Integer user_id,
                                         @Field("profile_image") File profile_im,
                                         @Field("name") String name,
                                         @Field("mobile") String mobile,
                                         @Field("class_id") Integer class_id,
                                         @Field("address") String address,
                                         @Field("country_id") Integer country_id,
                                         @Field("state_id") Integer state_id,
                                         @Field("city_id") Integer city_id,
                                         @Field("session_id") String session_id

---

Call responseBodyCall = ObjectFactory.getInstance().getRestClient(mcontext).getApiService().updateProfile(user_id,
                body, name, mobile, class_id, address, country_id, state_id, city_id,session_id);